# How to merge rotation image with the background image?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to merge two images after rotate the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399811/how-to-merge-two-images-after-rotate-the-image)

I have used two images the foreground image rotate, background image is stable. How to merge these two images? Its not properly working for me. Thanks in advance.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
CGRect backgroundImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
CGRect foregroundImageRect = CGRectMake(rsImageView.frame.origin.x, rsImageView.frame.origin.y, rsImageView.frame.size.width, rsImageView.frame.size.height);
[backgroundImageView.image drawInRect:backgroundImageRect];
[rsImageView.image drawInRect:foregroundImageRect];
overlappedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I am using this code. But not merge the rotation image. Its only merge the last image frame.

Comment: What have you tried? How have you failed? What are the errors? What is your code?

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
    CGRect backgroundImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    CGRect foregroundImageRect = CGRectMake(rsImageView.frame.origin.x, rsImageView.frame.origin.y, rsImageView.frame.size.width, rsImageView.frame.size.height);
    [backgroundImageView.image drawInRect:backgroundImageRect];
    [rsImageView.image drawInRect:foregroundImageRect];
    overlappedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   I tried like this. But the rotation image is not merged properly.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting large amounts of code in a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here imgDisplayImage is instance of UIInageVew,lastRotation is total Rotation angle

```
    //...code...//
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [self.imgDisplayImage center].x, [self.imgDisplayImage center].y);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, lastRotation);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                          -self.imgDisplayImage.frame.size.width * [[self.imgDisplayImage layer] anchorPoint].x,
                          -self.imgDisplayImage.frame.size.height * [[self.imgDisplayImage layer] anchorPoint].y);

        [self.imgDisplayImage.layer renderInContext:context];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    // . . .
```