# How to merge two images after rotate the image?

Tags: iphone

[image]

After rotate the image how to merge the rotation image? I using the below code, Its work fine for before the image rotation. How to fix this issue . Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
CGRect backgroundImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
CGRect foregroundImageRect = CGRectMake(rsImageView.frame.origin.x, rsImageView.frame.origin.y, rsImageView.frame.size.width, rsImageView.frame.size.height);

[backgroundImageView.image drawInRect:backgroundImageRect];
[rsImageView.image drawInRect:foregroundImageRect];
overlappedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Ya.Merge the image after rotation.

Comment: sorry i mean, image merge in while device orientation?

Comment: Not for orientation. Its a manual rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method call this after rotation:

```
-(UIImage *)getMergedImage
{
 UIImage mergedImage;
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImageView.frame.size)
 [backgroundImageView.layer  renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext];//bacgroundImageView here
 UIImage overLappedImage = [self getOverlappedImage];
 if(overLappedImage)
 {
   //CGRectMake(0,0,rsImageView.frame.width,rsImageView.frame.height)
   [overLappedImage drawInRect:rsImageView.frame blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];//TopMostImageView here
 }
 mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 return mergedImage;
}
```

---

Add this method to get overlappped Image.

```
-(UIImage *)getOverlappedImage
{
  UIImage overlappedImage;
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rsImageView.frame.size)
  [rsImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext]; //TopMostImageView here
  overlappedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return overlappedImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Its not woking for me. Please give some more ideas. I expect your ideas.

Comment: Hi Prince...Really great...your code is woking 100% perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want while device orientation use this code

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
    toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    //Your cgrectmake for landscape
}
else
{
    //Your cgrectmake for Portrait
}
}
```